# as3 - how to randomize object positions without colliding?

Tags: actionscript-3

If I have two instances called block1 and block2. And they move off the stage. It scrolls down the y position and it respawns back on top. But I don't want the x/y position colliding with the other blocks? I want it to respawn back to position, but I want it randomized but at the same time I don't want it touching each other?

Heres my code:

```
if (block1.y > stage.stageHeight)
{
    block1.y = -550;
    block1.x = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNum - minNum + 5)) + minNum);
}
```

I'm pretty sure I'm calculating the respawn coordinates the wrong way, but I'm not sure how to put it in a random x and y position without colliding with other blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple method can be just to spawn your box, do a collision check, then if collision, remove and respawn and recheck until you find an empty spot where it fits

This is obviously quite inefficient, but is pretty simple to implement quickly if you have some sort of collision detection already working. Keep in mind if there is no spot that it can fit in, then it'll loop forever so you may want to set a max try count or something of that sort.

How fast/well it'll actually work will depend on if the spawn area is pretty sparse or pretty dense, which will increase/decrease the percentage that it'll find a good empty spot the first few times.

There is some room for improvement, going down this path though, such as if your collision detection system gives a minimum translation vector, you could just move the new shape over and use that position to spawn.

Other simple methods could involve keeping track of known occupied positions and adjusting your random range to avoid those values.